# Unsaved model instances to related filters in tests for django 5.0

Tags: django, django-models

In Django 5 "passing unsaved model instances to related filters is no longer allowed" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/).

Basically before I had this method (only relevant code shown):

```
def make_payload(user, nonce, exclude_groups=None):
    exclude_groups = set(exclude_groups or [])
    relevant_groups = Group.objects.filter(internal_only=False).order_by("internal_name")
    filter_q = Q(user=user) & ~Q(pk__in=exclude_groups)
    add_groups = relevant_groups.filter(filter_q).values_list("internal_name", flat=True)
    ...
```

And tested it using this test method (only relevant code shown):

```
def test_builds_payload_not_activated(self):
    user = accounts.tests.factories.UserFactory.build(email_verified=False)

    payload = utils.make_payload(user, "nonce-nce")
    ...
```

Now obviously the instance as not been saved as it's a unit and not an integration test. This leads to `relevant_groups.filter(filter_q)` failing with `ValueError: Model instances passed to related filters must be saved`. Basically I've no idea how to fix the test as the code is still working in a real environment. Ideas welcome.

Comment: same here, did you find anything useful ?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `Q(user=user)` with `Q(user_id=user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

"Assuming you’ve assigned a pk for that object, I would try setting user._state.adding=False and user._state.db='default'"

Source: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/unsaved-model-instances-to-related-filters-in-tests-for-django-5-0/26586

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would save the object in the test.

That might not be unit-test-y enough for you but now that Django requires objects to be saved before passing to related filters, that's the only way to do this correctly.

Workarounds like setting `user._state.adding=False` etc would leave me concerned that it wasn't correctly replicating real-world behaviour. It feels like making a test work, rather than testing something.